# Use HuggingFace models locally

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I would like to use transformers especially HuggingFace Models as a part of my programming

my question is; Can I use and implement transformers and HuggingFace Models offline and in Spyder IDE (or any other IDE that I can use locally? (Of course, after downloading and installing all needed packages).

Thanks in advance.